# Default input formatter in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core 2 app I have an action with `[FromBody]` attribute. The argument is converted from JSON body to model object by ASP.NET engine.

But it only works if `Content-Type` of the request is set to `application/json`. If the header is not set, then *415 (Unsupported Media Type)* HTTP error is returned.

How to set the default formatter to be JSON for `[FromBody]` binding, so it will bind the model even if the `Content-Type` request header is not set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not specifying the content type, the default content type it assumes is 'text/plain'. You can enforce the application to treat the payload as json content with the below code,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                foreach (var formatter in config.InputFormatters)
                {
                    if (formatter.GetType() == typeof(JsonInputFormatter))
                        ((JsonInputFormatter)formatter).SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                            Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
                }
            }
            );
        }
```